# Slider Bar for date time javascript jquery. Need advice

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, range

I see this useful link to make a slider bar that does date ranges, but I look for one that would do Time and Dates. Ideally, I'm looking at times and date within a 3 day period. Also looking to be able to slide 2 points!

http://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/

Answer (score 1):

Got it mostly using `formatter: function (value)` http://jsfiddle.net/vM844/1861/